# Deleting everything after a pattern in Unix

Tags: regex, unix, sed, substitution

I have a string `replenishment_category string,Date string`, I want to delete everything starting with `Date` (including it), also the comma before it if it is present.

I have the string to be replaced stored in a variable:

```
PARTITION_COLUMN='Date'
```

I tried `sed` to replace everything after the variable `PARTITION_COLUMN`

```
echo "replenishment_category string,Date string" | sed "s/"$PARTITION_COLUMN".* //g"
```

but the output still has the string that follows the date:

```
replenishment_category string,string
```

How do I remove the `string` part and also the comma preceding the `Date`?

Comment: Any reason for downvoting this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "replenishment_category string,Date string" | sed "s/$PARTITION_COLUMN.*//"
```

Notice the space removed after `.*` and the double quote around the entire command.

Comment: It works , yes the space was the issue,is there way to remove the preceeding  ',' as weel so te final o/p only has " replenishment_category string" and not  "replenishment_category string,"

Comment: Yes, use: `"s/,$PARTITION_COLUMN.*//"`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove variable as well as comma before it so following `sed` may help you here.

```
echo "replenishment_category string,Date string" | sed "s/,$PARTITION_COLUMN.*//g"
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please do let me know reason of down vote here??

Answer (score 0):

`sed` would obviously work here:

`echo "replenishment_category string,Date string" | sed "s/\b,$PARTITION_COLUMN.*//"`

Output:

`replenishment_category string`

Comment: OP has specifically requested for shell variable should be used in `sed` command.

Comment: The variable won't expand because it's single quoted. The double quotes within the single quotes don't change that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with shell parameter expansion alone, assuming you have extended globs enabled (`shopt -s extglob`):

```
$ var='replenishment_category string,Date string'
$ part_column=Date
$ echo "${var%%?(,)"$part_column"*}"
replenishment_category string
```

- The `${word%%pattern}` expansion works without extended globs and removes the longest match of *`pattern`* from the end of `$word`.
- The `?(pattern)` extended pattern matches zero or one occurrences of *`pattern`* and is used to remove the comma if present.
- `"$part_column"*` matches any string that begins with the expansion of `$part_column`. Quoting it is not required in the example, but good practice to prevent glob characters from expanding.